# Looping back to beginning of code

Tags: java, loops

I've seen a few threads like this but I don't completely understand how I would implement it into my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {



    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException {



        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-1000: ");

        int n = reader.nextInt();

        if(90<=n && n<=110) System.out.println(n + " is close to 100");
        if(190<=n && n<=210) System.out.println(n + " is close to 200");
        if(290<=n && n<=310) System.out.println(n + " is close to 300");
        if(390<=n && n<=410) System.out.println(n + " is close to 400");
        if(490<=n && n<=510) System.out.println(n + " is close to 500");
        if(590<=n && n<=610) System.out.println(n + " is close to 600");
        if(690<=n && n<=710) System.out.println(n + " is close to 700");
        if(790<=n && n<=810) System.out.println(n + " is close to 800");
        if(890<=n && n<=910) System.out.println(n + " is close to 900");
        if(n>1000)System.out.println("Your number is too high");
        else System.out.println("Your number is not close to any 100s");


    }

}
```

I'd like it to somehow loop back to the user input part if the integer is over 1000.

Comment: Check your documentation for the while() {} constructs.

Comment: I'm really sorry but what would my "documentation" be and where could I find it?

Comment: Ask your teacher or search the web on java while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop and break out of it only if the number entered is below 1 or above 1000

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {



public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {


    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System. in );
    Boolean exit = false;

    while (!exit) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-1000: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt();
        if (n < 0 || n > 1000) {

            System.out.println("That number was invalid");
        } else {
            exit = true;
            if (90 <= n && n <= 110) System.out.println(n + " is close to 100");
            if (190 <= n && n <= 210) System.out.println(n + " is close to 200");
            if (290 <= n && n <= 310) System.out.println(n + " is close to 300");
            if (390 <= n && n <= 410) System.out.println(n + " is close to 400");
            if (490 <= n && n <= 510) System.out.println(n + " is close to 500");
            if (590 <= n && n <= 610) System.out.println(n + " is close to 600");
            if (690 <= n && n <= 710) System.out.println(n + " is close to 700");
            if (790 <= n && n <= 810) System.out.println(n + " is close to 800");
            if (890 <= n && n <= 910) System.out.println(n + " is close to 900");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This was it, thanks! Could you possibly explain why you put an exclamation mark on the beginning of "while (!flag)"?

Comment: So basically me saying while(exit) is the same as saying while(exit == true). The ! is the not operator. So saying while(!exit) is the same is while(exit != true). In summary it saying while exit does not have a value of true then do the loop. That's why setting exit equal to true stops the loop.

Answer (score 1):

*Try with this,*

```
boolean flag;
do {
    flag = false;
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1-1000: ");

    int n = reader.nextInt();

    if(90<=n && n<=110) System.out.println(n + " is close to 100");
    if(190<=n && n<=210) System.out.println(n + " is close to 200");
    if(290<=n && n<=310) System.out.println(n + " is close to 300");
    if(390<=n && n<=410) System.out.println(n + " is close to 400");
    if(490<=n && n<=510) System.out.println(n + " is close to 500");
    if(590<=n && n<=610) System.out.println(n + " is close to 600");
    if(690<=n && n<=710) System.out.println(n + " is close to 700");
    if(790<=n && n<=810) System.out.println(n + " is close to 800");
    if(890<=n && n<=910) System.out.println(n + " is close to 900");
    if(n>1000) {
        flag = true;
        System.out.println("Your number is too high, please try again");
    }
    else if (n < 90) {
        System.out.println("Your number is not close to any 100s");
    }
} while(flag);
```